# How to Project 3D Covariance Matrix to a given Image Plane (Pose)

Tags: math, 3d, computer-vision, covariance, kalman-filter

I have a 3x3 covariance matrix for 3d-point and I want to know the equivalent 2d covariance (for u,v in image plane) , given the image pose `[Xc,Yc,Zc,q0,q1,q2,q3]` ,

There's a long (geometric) way that the 3d covariance could be a 3d ellipse , then projecting it into plane give 2d ellipse ,lastly converting the ellipse to 2d matrix , but this is long,

Any direct way, to solve this algebraically will help

**P. S:** any clues or reference to a solution (no need for code) ,will also help, and I will rewrite an answer with code (in c++)

I  tagged also kalman filter , cause I think it's related to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How do I express analytically the covariance on a transformed variable?

You can get a first order approximation analytically by using the [uncertainty propagation equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty). In particular, the paragraph on non-linear combinations explains basically the following:

> Knowing the covariance `C_x` on a variable `x` and the jacobian matrix `J_f` of a function `f`, a first order approximation of the covariance on `f(x)` is given by: `C_f(x) = J_f . C_x . J_f^T`, where `.^T` is the transposition operator.

If I understood your question corerctly, you have the covariance on the 3D point expressed in the world coordinate frame, denoted `C_Xw`. You want the covariance of the projection of this point in the image plane, denoted `C_xi`. Let's denote by `f` the function mapping 3D world coordinates to image coordinates. Then we have: `C_xi = J_f . C_Xw . J_f^T`.

### How do I compute the jacobian matrix `J_f`?

In practice, `f` is the pinhole projection function and can be decomposed as follows: `f = f_intr o f_persp o f_pose`, where:

1. `f_intr` applies the intrinsics camera coefficients (i.e. horizontal & vertical focal lengths `fx` and `fy`, skew `s`, principal point coordinates `cx` and `cy`): `f_intr( [xn; yn] ) = [fx, s, cx; 0, fy, cy] . [xn; yn; 1] = [fx . xn + s . yn + cx; fy . yn + cy]`
2. `f_persp` applies the pinhole perspective model to a 3D point in the camera coordinate frame: `f_persp( [Xc; Yc; Zc] ) = [Xc/Zc; Yc/Zc]`
3. `f_pose` applies the 3D rigid transformation (i.e. rotation `R_cw`, translation `t_cw`) mapping a 3D point in the world coordinate frame into a 3D point in the camera coordinate frame: `f_pose( [Xw; Yw; Zw] ) = R_cw . [Xw; Yw; Zw] + t_cw`

The [chain rule of derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) helps expressing the derivative of composed functions:

> If `f = f_intr o f_persp o f_pose`, and denoting by `Xc=f_pose(Xw)`, `xn=f_persp(Xc)` and `xi=f_intr(xn)`, then we have the following:
>
> `J_f( Xw ) = J_f_intr( xn ) . J_f_persp( Xc ) . J_f_pose( Xw )`

The jacobian matrices of `f_intr`, `f_persp` and `f_pose` are quite easy to express analytically:

1. `f_intr` is linear in `xn`, hence `J_f_intr = [fx, s; 0, fy]` is a constant
2. `J_f_persp( Xc ) = [1/Zc, 0, -Xc/Zc²; 0, 1/Zc, -Yc/Zc²]`
3. `f_pose` is linear in `Xw`, hence `J_f_pose = R_cw` is a constant

### Final expression

Finally, we get the following analytical expression:

`C_xi = J_f . C_Xw . J_f^T`

where `J_f = [fx, s; 0, fy] . [1/Zc, 0, -Xc/Zc²; 0, 1/Zc, -Yc/Zc²] . R_cw`

Again, this is a first order approximation, but the pinhole projection function is "not very non linear", meaning that such an approximation is typically close enough for most applications.

Comment: That's great, I guess my answer is essentially wrong.

Comment: @YasinYousif Your initial approach ignores the perspective mapping. It might be close to a solution for an orthographic camera.

Comment: I've derived Jacobian a different way over here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497283/how-to-derive-camera-jacobian

Answer (score 0):

As Initial idea, the eigenvalue decomposition of a covariance matrix give a **rotation** matrix (eigenvectors) and magnitudes (eigenvalues).

if we know the rotation of the plane of the camera only as Matrix **Rc**, we may write:

> `N = Rc * eigenvectors;`
>
> `New_covariance = N*eigenvalues*inv(N) #main relation of decomposition`

but , we must make sure that the eigenvectors arranged as **X,Y,Z**

Lastly , we take the upper 2X2 Matrix of the **New_covariance** as the projected 2D Covariance (deleting the Z axis because it's perpendicular to image plane)

**Update:**

Here's an implemetation with Eigen library:

```
Eigen::Matrix3f points_cov_2d(VectorXf cov_p,Quaternionf quatcam ,
   float z_m,float f_x,float f_y){
 Matrix3f cov3d;
 cov3d << cov_p(0),cov_p(1),cov_p(2),
          cov_p(3),cov_p(4),cov_p(5),
          cov_p(6),cov_p(7),cov_p(8);
 SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXf> eigenSolver(cov3d);
 Vector3f eigs = eigenSolver.eigenvalues();
 Matrix3f vecs = eigenSolver.eigenvectors();
 Matrix3f n_vecs = quatcam.toRotationMatrix()*vecs;
 Matrix3f cov2d = n_vecs*eigs*n_vecs.inverse();
 cov2d = cov2d *(1/z_m/z_m);
 cov2d(0)*=(f_x*f_x);
 cov2d(4)*=(f_y*f_y);
 cov2d(3)*=(f_x*f_y);
 cov2d(1)*=(f_x*f_y);
 cov2d.block<1,3>(2,0) << 0,0,0;
 cov2d.block<3,1>(0,2) << 0,0,0;
 return cov2d;
};
```